# Remove Space from Hidden HTML Elemenets

Tags: html, forms, input, hidden

I need some help removing spaces after hiding certain HTML elements.  In context, I have a form, and I am using the GET method to send the results, so I need to hide certain fields.  However, when I use:

```
<input type = "hidden"...>
```

It leaves a blank line rather than no lines.

Any ideas?

Here is a view of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zRcqB/

Comment: in my form I have:

<form action = "www.myurl.com" method = "get" target = "_blank">
<input type = "hidden" name = "Description" value="MyDescrip" /><br />

Comment: Could you explain better what the problem is perhaps? Because I [fail to see the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/uXtxQ/).

Comment: Look Here: http://jsfiddle.net/zRcqB/

Comment: You have added `<br>` tags. What do you expect?

Comment: Thanks - I'm generating the form through a python script and for some reason accidentally appended that tag without realizing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fiddle you are following the hidden inputs with `<br />` tags. Remove those and you are good to go.

See updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/82ZwM/

Comment: Thanks - I'm generating the form through a python script and for some reason accidentally appended that tag without realizing!

Comment: Gotcha gotcha. Glad I could help.